# How to solve this HTML/CSS bug?

Tags: html, css, jsp

It's a fairly complex page where the logic and tags looks like this (please don't worry about the scriplets, it's just for testing:

```
<div id="avd" <%if(request.getParameter("s")==null || !request.getParameter("s").equals("avd")) { %>style="display: none;"<%} %>>
    <div class="fr10 smallg">
        F&ouml;rnamn Efternamn,<br>handl&auml;ggarkod
    </div>
    <div class="fl10"></div>
    <div class="fl20">Avdelad fr&aring;n:</div>
    <div class="fl20">
        <input type="text" id="avd_date" value="<%=ansokanInfo.getAvdf()%>" name="<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_AVDF%>"><input type="button" value="S&ouml;k" onClick="getElementById('popupA').style.display=''">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="fl10"></div>
    <div class="fl20">Datum ingivningsdag:</div>
    <div class="fl20">
        <input type="text" id="avd_ing" value="<%=ansokanInfo.getAvdIngivningsdag()%>" name="<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_AVD_INGIVNINGSDAG%>" value="<%=ansokanInfo.getIngivningsDatum()%>">&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="images/cal.gif" alt="" width="16" height="15" border="0" onclick="javascript:openCalWin('620','300','<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_AVD_INGIVNINGSDAG%>')">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The display get to look like this:

[image]

The expected look is this:

[image]

What is wrong?

```
*  {font-family:arial;}

.avnamn{ 
    color: #90002b; 
    font-size: 140%; 
    display: inline; 
    vertical-align: 3%; 
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.b{border:1px solid #000;}

.readonly{background-color: #CCC;}

.Webdings{
    font-family: Webdings;
    }

ul{margin-top: 0px}

.mt3{margin-top:-3px;}
.mt5p{margin-top:5px;}

.fontS80 {font-size: 80%;} 
a:link{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:visited{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:active{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }

.fontS75 {font-size: 75%;} 

.link{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;}

.link_sm{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;}

.link_sm{font-size: 70%;cursor: pointer;}

.small{font-size: 75%;}

.smallg{font-size: 75%;
color: #555;}

.ssmall{
    font-size: 65%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
}

.small60{font-size: 60%;}
.small50{
    font-size: 50%;
    color: #333;
}

.smallb{font-size: 85%;}

table{display:inline;}

h1{font-size: 130%;display:inline;}
h2{font-size: 100%;display:inline;}
h3{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h4{font-size: 70%;display:inline;}

h5{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hthin{
    font-size: 125%;
}

.th {text-align: left;}

td, th{font-size: 75%;
    vertical-align: text-top;}
.td_link{cursor: pointer;}
.td40{height:40px;}
.td60{height:60px;}

.thkant{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: left;
}

.bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
.bbV{border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_nbA {background-color:#CCC;}
.TB_bt, .TB_nb, .TB_db, .TB_bb {background-color:#efefdc;}

.hk {background-color:#d9ddb3;}

.hknot {background-color:#f9faf2;}
/*<!--F8F8F1-->*/
.TB_bt{border-top: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bt5{border-top: 5px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
.TB_bb2{border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;}
.TB_db{border-bottom: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000;}
.TB_tb{border-top: 2px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo{border: 2px solid #efefdc;}
.TB_bo_hk{border-top: 1px solid #efefdc;}


.TB_bo2{border: 1px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo2B{
border-top: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
border-left: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-right: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
}

.TD_bo{
    border-right: 1px solid #c1c1b3;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.TD_bo2{

    border-right: 0;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ytb{
    border-left:3px solid #efefdc;
    border-right:3px solid #efefdc;
}

.datum {
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: text-top;} 

.sub {background:#EAEAEA;}

.sub_meny, .sub_meny_r, .sub_meny_active, .sub_meny_sm{
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: text-top;}

.sub_meny_sm {
    font-size: 60%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}    

.sub_meny_search{
    position: absolute;
    right: 265px;
    font-size: 70%;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

.sub_meny_r{
    float:right;
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;}

.sub_meny_rm{margin-top:4px;}
.sub_meny_active{font-weight: bold;}

.flikkant1 {
    background-image: url(../images/fl1k.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;}

.inl_namn{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;}

.th{text-align: left;}
.tr{text-align: right;}

.g1{
    background-color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g2{
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g3{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.g4{
    background-color: #CCC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.popuphandlaggare{ 
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: groove;      
    border-width: 2px;      
    padding: 0px;      
    background-color: #FFF;     
    font-size: 70%;     
    position: absolute;     
    top: 900px; 
    }

.popupN{
    background-color: #F0F0E3;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.pin{padding: 6px;}

.fl10, .fl20, .fl30, .fl40, .fl50, .fl60, .fl70, .fl80, .fl90, .fl100 {
    padding-bottom:4px;color: #000000;
}

.over{
    background-color: #EFEFDC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.half{
    line-height:50%;
}

.quarter{
    line-height:25%;
}

.lh10{
    line-height:10%;
}

.checkmargin {margin-right: 25px;}    
.checkmarginL {margin-left: 25px;}    

.pusher {padding-left: 15px;}
.pusherR {margin-right: 40px;}

.rand3{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 3px;}
.rand1{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 1px;}

.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 4px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }
#details { width: 700px; color: #ffffff; }
.column1 {     color: #000000; margin: 0;      padding: 0;     width: 600px;     border:0;     float: left; }
.column2 {     color: #000000;margin: 0;      padding: 0;     border:0;     width: 80px;     float: right; }

.f200 {
    color: #000000;
}

.f210 {
    color: #000000;float: left;
}
.f220 {
    width: 400px;
}
.f1450 {
    width: 600px;
    float:left;
}
.f1550 {
    width: 150px;
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
}
.paddedcell {
    padding:15px;
}
.b2{border:2px solid #efefdc;}
.inp_sel{width: 80%;}

.fl21{float:left; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:150px;} .fl455{float:left; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:120px;} 

.form-bg {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.form-bg2 {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.data-bar {
  border-bottom:1px solid #fbfbf7;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 10px;
}

.left {
float:left;
width:200px;

}
.discount {
float:right;
width:500px;

}
.discounts {
width:900px;

}
.right {
float:right;
width:700px;
}
.yta20 {
background: #eeefdf;
width:1100px;
}

.yta2 {

width:1100px;
}

.data-box {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
}
#table td { 
margin:120px; 
} 

#personName {     float:left;     width:300px;   }  #otherDetails {     float:right;     width:450px;      }

.th_rad_sort {border-bottom: 2px solid #000000; text-decoration: none;}

a img { border: 0; outline:0;}

.f { float: right;     color: white; }

.handlaggare { width: 1000px; }

div.data-box-nat{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 600px;
}
div.data-box-pct{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 600px;
}

.popup{
    border-color: #000; 
    border-style: groove; 
    border-width: 2px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 75%;
}

.horizontal-gradient {
    background: #1a2adb; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%, #a1e6ed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1a2adb), color-stop(100%,#a1e6ed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a2adb', endColorstr='#a1e6ed',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: white;
    width: 1055px;
}

#topBar {width:100%; background-color:#EFEFDC; display:inline-block;}
#topBar h2 {float:left}
#close {position:relative; float:right;}
.fl1, .fl2, .fl5, .fl10, .fl15, .fl20, .fl22, .fl25, .fl30, .fl35, .fl40, .fl45, .fl50, .fl55, .fl60, .fl65, .fl70, .fl75, .fl80, .fl85, .fl90, .fl95, .fl100 { float: left;}
.fl1        {width: 1%;}
.fl2        {width: 2%;}
.fl5        {width: 5%;}
.fl10       {width: 10%;}
.fl13       {width: 13%;}
.fl15       {width: 15%;}
.fl20       {width: 20%;}
.fl21       {width: 21%;}
.fl22       {width: 22%;}
.fl23       {width: 23%;}
.fl24       {width: 23%;}
.fl25       {width: 25%;}
.fl30       {width: 30%;}
.fl35       {width: 35%;}
.fl40       {width: 40%;}
.fl45       {width: 45%;}
.fl50       {width: 50%;}
.fl55       {width: 55%;}
.fl60       {width: 60%;}
.fl65       {width: 65%;}
.fl70       {width: 70%;}
.fl75       {width: 75%;}
.fl80       {width: 80%;}
.fl85       {width: 85%;}
.fl90       {width: 90%;}
.fl95       {width: 95%;}
.fl100      {width: 100%;}

.fr1, .fr5, .fr10, .fr15, .fr20, .fr25, .fr30, .fr35, .fr40, .fr45, .fr50, .fr55, .fr60, .fr65, .fr70, .fr75, .fr80, .fr85, .fr90, .fr95, .fr100 {
    float: right;
    }
.fr1        {width: 1%;}    
.fr5        {width: 5%;}
.fr10       {width: 10%;}
.fr15       {width: 15%;}
.fr20       {width: 20%;}
.fr25       {width: 25%;}
.fr30       {width: 30%;}
.fr35       {width: 35%;}
.fr40       {width: 40%;}
.fr45       {width: 45%;}
.fr50       {width: 50%;}
.fr55       {width: 55%;}
.fr60       {width: 60%;}
.fr65       {width: 65%;}
.fr70       {width: 70%;}
.fr75       {width: 75%;}
.fr80       {width: 80%;}
.fr85       {width: 85%;}
.fr90       {width: 90%;}
.fr95       {width: 95%;}
.fr100      {width: 100%;}

.clearL     {clear: left;}
.clearR     {clear: right;}
.clear      {clear: both;}
```

Comment: Cant really see without the CSS

Comment: Please reduce your markup to just html and make a fiddle. Having server side markup for a css issue is not as useful.

Comment: @Asad Thing is a fiddle might not reproduce the bug. The bug appears on page load only and not when I change the field display from the option choice. I can try and make a fiddle but I think it might not reproduce the bug.

Comment: @Will I put the CSs there for you to see. I hope you can think of what is wrong without the stanardized answer that I should make a fiddle from a webpage that has 5000 rows and 3 files of CSS. Of course it's best to reproduce the bug with minimal code but in practice that might take several days and I want to solve this today.

Comment: @PaulOwens Thanks for the comment. I've now updated the question with the CSS. I've been told to make a fiddle and if we can't see why with the current display I might be forced to reproduce this bug as a fiddle but the bug only display right on page load and not after a change in the layout triggered by an option select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to clear the float before these lines:

```
<div class="fl10"></div>
<div class="fl20">Avdelad fr&aring;n:</div>
```

Just add `<div class="clear"></div>` like you did here:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl10"></div>
<div class="fl20">Datum ingivningsdag:</div>
```

Or even better, add the `.clearL` class to the first `div`, like this:

```
<div class="fl10 clearL"></div>
<div class="fl20">Avdelad fr&aring;n:</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a lot better with your changes.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, it's a suggestion:

It would be easier for you to control and maintain your code if you were to use rows instead of confusing clears, plus using semantic markup always helps when reading back through your html:

```
<div class="field-row">
  <label for="my_field">
    My Field Label
  </label>
  <div class="field-wrapper">
    <input id="my_field" name="my_field" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-row">
  <!-- You can continue each field in another row //-->
</div>
```

By using the parent and child nature of HTML you gain extra benefits with what you can do with positioning and layout - i.e. you could shift the entire row with padding or margins, or you could float the whole row again arround another element.

Then to "clear" each row so they sit correctly, all you would need to do is the following:

```
.field-row {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* 
     overflow hidden is easier to work with than `clear:both` 
     mainly because you can set it on the parent and it is the
     parent that gets corrected. clearing tends to affect the
     surrounding elements, which makes it tricky to follow.
  */
}

.field-row label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.field-wrapper label {
  float: left;
}
```